# i have a login module and i was just wondering how can i update the users last login date ? the list goes on and on every time i log in

Tags: php

here is my login code in php i want to update the users_table and insert the last login date on the database. It seems that i am just entering the login date and i am not updating it any advice?

```
     session_start();
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $uname = $_POST['uname'];
     $pw = $_POST['pw'];
    //retrieve users from database

    require_once('db.php');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username="'.mysql_escape_string($uname).'" AND      password="'.mysql_escape_string(md5($pw)).'"
            LIMIT 0, 1
    ';
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);   
    $count = mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if($count > 0) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pw;
        $date = date ('Y-m-d');

        //this code will insert the login date on the database
        mysql_query("INSERT into users_table (last_login) VALUES ('$date')  ");
        header('Location: products_list.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?error=1');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're using the deprecated `mysql_` functions -- I highly recommend the newer `mysqli` functions or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of INSERTing a new record, you should UPDATE the existing record.

```
mysqli_query('UPDATE users_table SET last_login=NOW() WHERE username=' .
    mysqli_real_escape_string($uname));
```

Better yet, get the user's ID and use that for the UPDATE:

```
$user = $qry->fetch_object();
mysqli_query('UPDATE users_table SET last_login=NOW() WHERE id=' .
    mysqli_real_escape_string($user->id));
```